# postfix virtual map regular expression

Tags: postfix, email-server, regular-expressions

I am trying to create a small virtual_alias_maps fiel for postfix-pcre:

```
.*@subdom\.domain\.com test@other.org
```

But I get this error:

```
warning: pcre map /etc/postfix/virtual, line 1: unknown regexp option "c": skipping this rule
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
/^.*@(subdom)\.(domain)\.(com)$/ test@other.org
```